# How can I add silverlight primitives dynamically with draggable and resizable properties?

Tags: c#, silverlight

Well I wanna please ask you how can I implement a ribbon for example that have primitives like line, ellipse, rectangle, point, etc ... So that the user can drag any of these primitives from the ribbon and drag it in the grid where he can drag, drop and resize the added primitive freely.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that the [Silverlight toolkit drag and drop classes](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/10/19/silverlight-toolkit-adds-drag-drop-support.aspx) won't help you here since you won't be using any standard drop target, so your options for the drag and drop are:

- Implement it manually, based on mouse events. [Here's a basic example from the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189066%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). Also, here's a nice article on how you could do this with behaviors: [Expression Blend 3: Trying a drag-and-drop behavior](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2009/05/08/test-post-1.aspx).
- Use [ComponentOne DragDropManager](http://demo.componentone.com/Silverlight/ControlExplorer/#DragDropManager/DemoListBox) (not free).
- Use [Telerik DragDropManager](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#DragAndDrop/FirstLook) (not free).

Comment: Thank you very much alfonso :) all these examples are great but the don't explain how to add a resizable property to my added primitive :(